# Certificado e conexão SSL no Wildfly

Tags: jboss, ssl, wildfly

Segui essa resposta dessa pergunta no SO para configurar o SSL: [how to configure ssl in wildfly 8.2.0 server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29159501/4725255)

Antes sem essa configuração não funcionava o acesso na porta `8443` que é a porta que faz a conexão com as aplicações de maneira segura.

Porém agora sempre quando acesso uma aplicação a partir da porta `8443` aparece para fazer o download de um arquivo que não sei do que se trata, mas acredito que é o certificado um certificado SSL que devemos colocar no cliente. Não sei o que devo fazer com esse arquivo, existem mais passos para configurar o SSL?

O nome do arquivo é `TecnologiaExemplo` que ainda não foi salvo, porém conforme mudamos de aplicação na URL surge um novo download com uma sugestão diferente de nome de arquivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido, para acessar de maneira "segura", ou seja, sem um certificado assinado por uma empresa que emite certificados SSL foi incluido na URL o `https://` e não somente `localhost:8443/aplicacao`.

Depois disso no meu web.xml da aplicação coloquei o seguinte XML para redicionar de HTTP para o HTTPS não ocorrendo mais o problema de pedir para baixar esse arquivo:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>WEB_APPLICATION_NAME</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Onde `WEB_APPLICATION_NAME` é o nome da sua aplicação.